# iPad 4 screen cracked

Tags: ipad, screen

It looks like hair got under the screen protector .  If I want to just keep using it, am I in danger?  Or will the screen protector protect me?

Comment: Would you drive with a cracked windshield? Pretty much the same real-life experience will need to come into play for you to decide your aversion to risk. If something unexpected happens, you have more chance to get injured if the glass is already broken in both cases. Perhaps you can elaborate on what danger you seek to avoid so that an outsider could offer advice?

Comment: To be honest, screen protectors are quite durable. And since you likely aren't doing anything other than gently rubbing or talking the screen, I really doubt you'll cut yourself. I've seen people use shattered screens and do so without harm (though one wonders how they can see anything). Glaziers frequently tape up giant panes of glass till they can replace them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of local third-party repair people who specialize in this sort of problem, and may be able to replace the glass for a lot less than Apple. You may want to search around for people who repair Apple laptop repair, as they are likely to be able to refer you to someone local.

Comment: I would avoid these places. Most will use highly inferior components resulting in poor performance (unregistered taps, etc.). There's a reason why they offer the service at a fraction of the cost Apple does. Even those that say they use the same parts Apple does often lie. Everyone I've known who has used some 3rd party, unlicensed outfit as regretted it (and I've know a fair amount that have done it).

Comment: The person I know locally who does this works out of their home, and was recommended by a reputable repair shop.  I had a problem with the screen connection in an old PowerBook, which no one else would even touch.  The fix was effective and affordable, and allowed me to extend the life of the PowerBook for a number of months.  While I would prefer Apple service in most cases, it can be too expensive to consider in many instances.

Answer (score 0):

If the cracked area is small, you can keep using it with a screen protector on the screen. It is safe. But, if the cracked area is large and the glass is broken, you'd better replace the screen with a new touch screen.